# C++ SendMessage trying to receive string

Tags: c++, sendmessage

Working with C++, I've spent way to many hours already trying to figure this out.  This code is from a working program, I'm rewriting it in C#, but there is some things happening I do not understand.

The below code is exactly what runs when I press "Step Into". How is it going from ::SendMessage(...) to ::OnCopyData(..) with pCopyDataStruct containing data now?

main.cpp

```
void COTP::main()
{
    //string will be returned using WM_COPYDATA message
    ::SendMessage(hWnd, 33508, (WPARAM)GetSafeHwnd(), 11);

    // WPARAM is a typedef for UINT_PTR which is an unsigned int.
}
```

afxwin2.inl

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE HWND CWnd::GetSafeHwnd() const
    { return this == NULL ? NULL : m_hWnd; }
```

main.cpp

```
BOOL COTP::OnCopyData(CWnd* pWnd, COPYDATASTRUCT* pCopyDataStruct) 
{
    CString str, str2;

    switch (pCopyDataStruct->dwData)
    {
        case JRC_COPYDATA_ID_TRACK_FILENAME:
            str = (LPCTSTR)pCopyDataStruct->lpData;
            break;
    }
}
```

Any help super appreciated, I have looked thru all the msdn documents that I can tonight, it just seems like I'm missing something simple somewhere. Thought it might be a callback, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: What does your stack look like when you are inside OnCopyData in the debugger?

Comment: You need to understand windows message pumps (SendMessage will make a call into Windows and the the function you end up in is determined by how the pump is wired up in your application) and how the MFC was designed to use them. The book Undocumented MFC explains this beautifully.

Comment: Call stack is what I was needing thank you. LRESULT CALLBACK was the very first one :).  This part here looks like it may take a while to convert into C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright got it figured out now. With the help of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637914/marshalling-structs-from-wm-copydata-messages) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/162674a7-368c-452b-91b0-9a8d4c5923ce).  Below is what I'm currently using for C#.  This is by no means finished code, but this does work and is good for learning purposes.

Click calculate button,

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int hwnd = 0;
        hwnd = Win32.FindWindow("The App pulling from", "Window");

        int s = (int)GetActiveWindow();
        int s3 = Win32.SendMessage(hwnd, 33508, s, 11);
```

Then what happens is a callback occurs and activates WndProc(ref Message m),

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Prevents error creating window handle message.
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        // WM_COPYDATA
        // m.Msg = 0x4a
        //msg=0x4a (WM_COPYDATA) hwnd=0x251e62 wparam=0x69063e lparam=0x1c42cca0 result=0x0
        if (m.Msg == 0x4a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
            WndProc(m.HWnd, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
        }
    } 

    public struct CopyDataStruct : IDisposable
    {
        public IntPtr dwData;
        public int cbData;
        public IntPtr lpData;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.lpData != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                LocalFree(this.lpData);
                this.lpData = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public unsafe struct DataStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 300)]
        public string s;
        public double d;
        public char c;
    };

    protected void WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        CopyDataStruct cps = (CopyDataStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(CopyDataStruct));
        DataStruct data = (DataStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(cps.lpData, typeof(DataStruct));
        // data.s is what we needed.
        Console.WriteLine(data.s);
    }
```

Thank you very much to everyone that replied! I am confident I would have given up if not for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

The code is sending a message (33508) to a specific window.  Apparently the receiving window processes that message by sending a `WM_COPYDATA` message to the `HWND` you passed in the `WPARAM` in the original `SendMessage()` call.  It's essentially implementing a callback mechanism.

The original message number (33508) is not one the standard Win32 messages (at least not that I recognize), so it's likely a custom message.  Also, the fact that it's using `WM_COPYDATA` to respond would suggest that the receiving window is in a different process (i.e., not owned by your application).